# How to add typings for a function wrapper in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, strong-typing

I am trying to write a small cache wrapper in typescript (simplified pseudo demo code):

```
const cache = {};
export function cachify<T, V>(name:string, getFunction: (i:V)=>Promise<T>): (i:V) => Promise<T> {
  return function() {
    return cache[name] || getFunction.apply(this,arguments)
  }
})
```

This works great if my function has only one argument e.g.

```
function isNameFancy(name:string) {
  return Promise.resolve(true)
}
const isNameFancyWithCache = cachify(isNameFancy)
```

However as i specified `i:V` this only valid for one argument.

If I have a second function e.g. `isPersonFancy` it won't work:

```
function isPersonFancy(personAge: number, personName: string) {
  return Promise.resolve(true)
}
const isPersonFancyWithCache = cachify(isPersonFancy)
```

How do I have to change my cachify function types so that it works for both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare other signatures for the `cachify` function:

```
const cache = {};
export function cachify<T, V>(name: string, getFunction: (i: V) => Promise<T>): (i: V) => Promise<T>;
export function cachify<T, V1, V2>(name: string, getFunction: (i: V1, j: V2) => Promise<T>): (i: V1, j: V2) => Promise<T>;
export function cachify(name: string, getFunction: (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>): (...args: any[]) => Promise<any> {
    return function () {
        return cache[name] || getFunction.apply(this,arguments)
    }
};

function isNameFancy(name: string) {
    return Promise.resolve(true)
}
const isNameFancyWithCache = cachify("isNameFancy", isNameFancy); // (i: string) => Promise<boolean>

function isPersonFancy(personAge: number, personName: string) {
    return Promise.resolve(true)
}
const isPersonFancyWithCache = cachify("isPersonFancy", isPersonFancy); // (i: number, j: string) => Promise<boolean>
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20cache%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0Aexport%20function%20cachify%3CT%2C%20V%3E(name%3A%20string%2C%20getFunction%3A%20(i%3A%20V)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3CT%3E)%3A%20(i%3A%20V)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3CT%3E%3B%0Aexport%20function%20cachify%3CT%2C%20V1%2C%20V2%3E(name%3A%20string%2C%20getFunction%3A%20(i%3A%20V1%2C%20j%3A%20V2)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3CT%3E)%3A%20(i%3A%20V1%2C%20j%3A%20V2)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3CT%3E%3B%0Aexport%20function%20cachify(name%3A%20string%2C%20getFunction%3A%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cany%3E)%3A%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cany%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20cache%5Bname%5D%20%7C%7C%20getFunction.apply(this%2Carguments)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20isNameFancy(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.resolve(true)%0A%7D%0Aconst%20isNameFancyWithCache%20%3D%20cachify(%22isNameFancy%22%2C%20isNameFancy)%3B%20%2F%2F%20(i%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cboolean%3E%0A%0Afunction%20isPersonFancy(personAge%3A%20number%2C%20personName%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.resolve(true)%0A%7D%0Aconst%20isPersonFancyWithCache%20%3D%20cachify(%22isPersonFancy%22%2C%20isPersonFancy)%3B%20%2F%2F%20(i%3A%20number%2C%20j%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cboolean%3E))